# VS Code - Organize Imports functionality behaving differently between users in the same project with the same settings

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

Recently I discovered the "Organize Imports" feature from VS Code. From what I read, it could only be applied locally without script, just opening file by file and triggering it, so I just did in our project. I can't find any kind of documentation or configuration possible values for it, but people state that it's compatible with ESlint and Prettier.

I've had no problems with it and everything has been working fine, but when a developer other than me opened our project and triggered the action to organize imports, the files were modified and the imports were sorted differently.

We are using the same code/branch, the same project, and same VS Code version, extensions and configurations (if they affect the code, such as actions on save, tabs, etc.).

Is there any hidden setting for *Organize Imports* that we can check to see if it's any different between us? Is there any kind of third-party library that does the same and is configurable at a project level so we don't have to worry by VS Code applying its own rules?

Comment: 1) is this a JS or a TS project? If TS, do you both have the same version of TS installed for the project? Check `npm list typescript` on both machines. 2) please provide a [mre] showing the before and after on both machines 3) please state exactly what VS Code version you both have installed.

Comment: does this issue ticket and any of the info there have any relevance to your issue? https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/52292 or this? https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode/issues/716 (are you and your colleague actually using prettier?)

Comment: It could have something to do @starball! Thank you so much for the info, I'll look into them and will keep an eye.

Comment: please do also check the things I asked in my first comment and come back with what you find.